# Quantitative comparision between x and 1/x

Tags: gre-exam

Following is a GRE question called quantitative comparison.

> Quantity A =  $x$
>
> Quantity B = $1/x$
>
> $-1<x<0$
>
> Options are as follows:
>
> - a) Quantity A is bigger
> - b) Quantity B is bigger
> - c) Quantity A and B are equal
> - d) Cannot determine

The answer when solved as it is A which I verified. But the way I did the sum was to simplify it first by removing fractions. So I multiplied $x$ on both sides.

After multiplication, I get

Quantity A = $x^2$
Quantity B = $1$

After simplification when I applied the values I am getting Quantity B as big.

> 1) What am I doing wrong?
>
> 2) Is there specific conditions under which I can only simplify?

Comment: I'll just put this hint here to address your confusion: Note that Quantity A $\not= x^2$! What you have there is $x\times\text{Quantity A}= (\text{Quantity A})^2=x^2$ and $x\times \text{Quantity B}=1$

Answer (score 2):

When  $X$ is between $-1$ and $0$, except when $X = 0$, then $A>B$.

Try it with, say, $X = -1/2$, as an example:

$A = \frac {-1/2}1 = -1/2,$ and $B = \frac 1{-1/2} = -2$. Hence, since $-1/2 > -2$, $A\gt B$.

**If $x$ is between $-1$ and $0$, as the edited post claims, then the correct answer is $(a)$.**

---

If $x < -1$, Then $B>A$.

---

If $X = 1$ or $X = -1$, then $\;A=B$.

---

If $X \gt 0$, but $X<1$, Then $B>A$.

---

When $X > 1$, then $A>B$.

Comment: Sorry but I messed up the syntax for math for defining the range. Can you please update your answer? Specifically pointing to 1) and 2) –

Comment: I hope the update is clearer for you now.

Answer (score 0):

If $-1<x<0$ then $B>A$, the correct answer is $b)$.

Indeed, suppose $A\geq B$, then $x^2\geq 1$ ans so $x\leq -1$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry but I messed up the syntax for math. Can you please update your answer? Specifically pointing to 1) and 2)

Comment: I don't understand what you want.

Comment: The range is between -1 and 0. I solved it got A as answer but when I simplify the equation and then solve it I get B as the answer. Why? What should I be careful about if I am simplifyinh

Answer (score 0):

The answer has to be a) Quantity A is greater than B
Here's why:

Since |x| is between 0 and 1 that itself should convince you that 1/x > x

So magnitude of B is greater than A. But since x is also negative the greater quantity will in fact be smaller. Hence Quantity A is greater.

What the other guy did wrong was:

Assume A>B

=> x > 1/x

But at this point when you multiply by 'x' you must remember that x is a negative number

Hence the inequality also flips:

$x^2$ < 1

Which is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is (a), that Quantity A is bigger. This is equivalent to saying that on the given range, that $x > \frac{1}{x}$. Let's look at why.

For $-1 < x < 0$, we really need to focus just on the left-hand inequality, namely that $-1 < x$. If we divide both sides by $x$ *noting that $x$ is negative*, then we find that
$$
\frac{-1}{x} > \frac{x}{x} = 1
$$
where we have reversed the inequality since $x < 0$. Now, mulitply both sides by -1 to get (again, reversing the inequality that
$$
-\frac{1}{x} < -1 < x
$$
but this is exactly saying that quantity B is less than quantity A on the given range. Hence (a) is the answer.